# how to set a react js header title to an element of an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I currently have a header component in my react js website and I want to set the title of it to an element of an array, but I cant seem to figure out how. here is my code

```
import Header from './components/Header';

var shoppinglist = []
var currentitem = ""
const App = () => {
  function getData(val){
    console.warn(val.target.value)
    currentitem = val.target.value;
  }
  function logData() {
    shoppinglist.push(currentitem)
    console.log(shoppinglist)
  }
  function deleteItem() {
    shoppinglist.pop()
    console.log(shoppinglist)
    console.log(shoppinglist[0])
  }
  return (
    <div className="Container">
        <Header title = "grocery list" />
        <input type="text" onChange={getData}></input>
        <button onClick={logData}>add item to list</button>
        <button onClick={deleteItem}>delete item</button>
        <div className="listItems">
          <Header title = {shoppinglist[0]} />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

how would i set the header title to shoppinglist[0]?

Comment: Could you provide the error message you get and the expected content of shoppinglist? Is it just an array of strings or an array of objects?

Comment: the expect content would for example be if I put the word bob in the input box and hit add to list button, the header would be named bob, there is no error message, it just doesnt change to the elemetn in the array

Comment: it is an array of strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have React state in order to render your content - in your case title.
You can read more in [react.js](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html)

One way of achieving what you asked in question: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-wildflower-uvusd?file=/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState(null);
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState(null);
  function getData(val) {
    console.warn(val.target.value);
    setInput(val.target.value);
  }
  function deleteItem() {
    setTitle(null);
  }
  return (
    <div className="Container">
      <input type="text" onChange={getData}></input>
      <button onClick={() => setTitle(input)}>add item to list</button>
      <button onClick={deleteItem}>delete item</button>
      {title && (
        <div>
          <p>{title}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dynamic component in react you have to use state-variables. Else React doesn't re-render your code. This could look like this with React Hooks:

```
import Header from './components/Header';

var currentitem = ""
const App = () => {
  const [shoppinglist, setShoppinglist] = useState([]);

  function getData(val){
    console.warn(val.target.value)
    currentitem = val.target.value;
  }

  function addItem() {
    shoppinglist.push(currentitem)
    setShoppinglist([...shoppinglist])
  }

  function deleteItem() {
    shoppinglist.pop()
    setShoppinglist([...shoppinglist])
  }

  return (
    <div className="Container">
        <Header title = "grocery list" />
        <input type="text" onChange={getData}></input>
        <button onClick={addItem}>add item to list</button>
        <button onClick={deleteItem}>delete item</button>
        <div className="listItems">
          <Header title = {shoppinglist[0]} />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```